# Is anything known of יהודא בן טיטוס?

Tags: names, family-members, maseches-bikkurim

In [Yerushalmi Bikkurim 11b](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Bikkurim.11b.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)(end) a person by the name יהודא בן טיטוס is mentioned. I would like to know if this person is the son of the famed roman emperor Titus (unlikely as that may be) or if any other information is known about him.

Comment: Perhaps Titus raped his mother?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Or maybe it's an unlucky Jew who happens to have the name Titus.

Comment: @Double doubtful considering רב מרי בר רחל

Comment: @user6591 Doubtable perhaps, but if your dad was the emperor of rome that'd be pretty notable

Comment: The Venice edition variously spells his name as יהודה בן טיטס, יודה בר טיטס and יודה בר טיטוס. It is unlikely, but certainly not impossible, that all the forms were identically corrupted. Note also the existence of רבי חייה בר טיטס (Terumot 5, 45c).

Answer (score 2):

According to one opinion, perhaps this can be explained as a mistake with ס and ט, making his name Yehuda bar Situs, not Titus. (See [Toledos Tannaim v'Amoraim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43957&st=&pgnum=145)).

Comment: I think the first pshat there is more interesting. Seems like R' Chamma gave him this name because he was in Rome. I would suggest fleshing out this answer a bit. Pointing out that your source directly addressed the issue at hand and emphatically states thus can't be titus's child. In any event +1.

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is that there was no such person. The text you link to has the following insertion prior to Ben Titus.

א"ר חמא <בן> יהודא בן טיטוס הוה ברומי ומנוניה ע"מ דיחזור

With that insertion it is saying that Chama ben Yehuda said that Ben Titus was in Rome. So there would not be a Yehuda ben Titus.

Comment: your reading doesn't prove there was no such person, just that the first name may not be yehuda. furthermore the flow of the gemara would indicate not to read it like that, all the previous examples have the person's first name, this is done to strengthen the proof that someone outside Israel can be appointed if he returns.

Comment: @rikitikitembo I think you did not read my answer properly. #1 I said it is a possible explanation. #2 I said there would not be a Yehuda ben Titus, I did not say there is no Ben Titus.

Comment: I don't think the issue was whether this person's first name was Yehudah. The issue was the father's name which you have not resolved.

Comment: @user6591 The question asked was "I would like to know if this person is the son of the famed roman emperor Titus (unlikely as that may be) or if any other information is known about him" the possible answer given is that there may not have been such a  person. If the issue is what you think it is, then let the questioner clarify the question.